# Comando personalizado Django

Tags: django

Saludos estoy intentando crear un comando personalizado en Django, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Unknown command: 'sincronizar'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

La estructura de mi proyecto es:

```
inventarios
 - management
   -commands
    -__init__.py
    -sincronizar.py
  -__init__.py
  -__init__.pyc
 -otra_ap
 -otra_app2
```

mi codigo:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        self.stdout.write("Sincronizando....")
```

Lo ejecuto de la siguiente manera:

```
python manage.py sincronizar
```

quiza alguien me podria guiar que estoy haciendo mal o que falta gracias de antemano..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que se debe realizar es dentro de una **APP** crear un directorio denominado **management** dentro de este creamos un nuevo directorio con el nombre **commands**.

Bien dentro de este directorio **commands** crearemos el archivo con nuestro comando , el nombre es relativo a lo que hara el comando, es decir si voy hacer un comando para saber la hora no le pondre **a.py**, para este caso lo denominare "**hora_actual.py**"

Dentro de este archivo tendra lo siguiente:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Muestra la hora actual'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time = timezone.now().strftime('%X')
        self.stdout.write("Son %s" % time)
```

bien grabamos los cambios en el archivo y desde la consola de comandos ponemos lo siguiente:

```
python manage.py hora_actual
```

tras lo cual la salida sera:

```
Son 13:05:10
```

asi de sencillo podemos crear comandos para Django personalizados, para mayor referencia y comandos mas completos recomendare el siguiente Link de **Vitor Freitas**:

[How to Create Custom Django Management Commands](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html)

Espero sea de su utilidad..!!